# MySQL (or C#) not matching doubles or decimals

Tags: c#, mysql, string, double, decimal

Why does MySQL, or C# I don't know which one, not like matching double or decimal variables? It will match strings but I need a double or a decimal as I need to match greater or less than with decimal places. It does not match anything at all with decimal or double and gives no errors. This is my code:

```
double lat5 = -26.00033;
string Lati = "-26.00033";
decimal lat6 = decimal.Parse(Lati, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//this
CommandString = "SELECT * FROM lapdetails2 WHERE Latitude = -26.00033";
//and this work
CommandString = "SELECT * FROM lapdetails2 WHERE Latitude = '" + Lati + "'";
//but this
CommandString = "SELECT * FROM lapdetails2 WHERE Latitude = '" + lat5 + "'";
//and this do not work
CommandString = "SELECT * FROM lapdetails2 WHERE Latitude = '" + lat6 + "'";
```

Data in MySQL DB is DOUBLE(10,5).

EDIT: This is a parameterised query I tried:

```
CommandString = "SELECT * FROM lapdetails2 WHERE Latitude = @Latitude";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(CommandString);
cmd.Connection = DB.ConnectSQL;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", lat6);
cmd.Connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I also changed the DB data to DECIMAL(8,5) as per Rick James' suggestion and it still does not work.

Edit 2: I fixed this with a stored procedure (not very efficient but it works).

````
CREATE DEFINER=```localhost` PROCEDURE `coord_pro`(IN Longi1 double(8,5), IN Longi2 double(8,5), IN lat double(8,5))
BEGIN

create table tmp engine=memory select * 
from lapdetails2 where Latitude = lat AND Longitude >= Longi2 AND Longitude <= Longi1;

END
````

where 
`Longi1 = actualLong * 1.00001;`
and 
`Longi2 = actualLong * 0.99991;`

and then just read the values from `tmp` and depending on your precision there should only be one row.

Comment: Why are you surrounding the value with tick marks? Have you tried using this with a parameterized query?

Comment: Tried parameterised query it didn't work for the same reason my concatenated string (that's what the ' ' and + are for). I think it's got something to do with MySQL and C# only dealing in strings when it comes to SQL quieries.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like that you have to use `InvariantCulture` when *converting to string*:

```
// this should be OK
CommandString = "SELECT * FROM lapdetails2 WHERE Latitude = '" + lat5.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "'";
```

using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` ensures that `.` will be used as a *decimal separator*. A better aproach is to eliminate apostrophes `'` as well, and let DMBS compare *numbers*, not *strings*:

```
CommandString = "SELECT * FROM lapdetails2 WHERE Latitude = " + lat5.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That would work but it's converting it to a string and I need decimal or double.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use `(M,N)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, it leads to an extra rounding.

Use `DECIMAL(8,5)` if you always have 5 decimal places on your lat/lng numbers.  Decimal will compare exactly against -26.00033, with or without quotes.

In general it is unwise to compare for equality numbers that are inherently "floating point", such as latitudes/longitudes.

When working in C#, be sure to round to 5 decimal places and present to MySQL a string, not a `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for consistency.  (Perhaps format `%.5f` works in C# like C?)

**Addenda**

Given a table with `d DECIMAL(18,4)`:

```
mysql> SELECT d, d<1.2346, d<'1.2346',
                 d=1.2346, d='1.2346',
                 d>1.2346, d>'1.2346'  FROM `dec184` WHERE d = 1.2346;
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| d      | d<1.2346 | d<'1.2346' | d=1.2346 | d='1.2346' | d>1.2346 | d>'1.2346' |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 1.2346 |        0 |          0 |        1 |          1 |        0 |          0 |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

When the client (C#, in your case) builds the value, it must convert to a string and optionally quote it.  Notice how `1.2346` works correctly in all cases.

Now, let's change things.  `dx` is declared `FLOAT`:

```
mysql> SELECT d, dx, dx<1.2346, dx<'1.2346',
                     dx=1.2346, dx='1.2346',
                     dx>1.2346, dx>'1.2346' FROM `dec184` WHERE d = 1.2346;
+--------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| d      | dx     | dx<1.2346 | dx<'1.2346' | dx=1.2346 | dx='1.2346' | dx>1.2346 | dx>'1.2346' |
+--------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| 1.2346 | 1.2346 |         1 |           1 |         0 |           0 |         0 |           0 |
+--------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Notice how `dx` happens to be below the constant.  To verify, let's trick MySQL into providing a more precise value.  (Note:  `FLOAT` has room for only about 7 significant digits, stored in 24 *bits*.)

```
mysql> SELECT dx, dx+0 FROM `dec184` WHERE d = 1.2346;
+--------+--------------------+
| dx     | dx+0               |
+--------+--------------------+
| 1.2346 | 1.2345999479293823 |
+--------+--------------------+
```

Or...

```
mysql> SELECT ROUND(dx,5), ROUND(dx,9) FROM `dec184` WHERE d = 1.2346;
+-------------+-------------+
| ROUND(dx,5) | ROUND(dx,9) |
+-------------+-------------+
|     1.23460 | 1.234599948 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: This is what I thought I needed but I need to select values from DB between two given values, that's why I need double or decimal comparison. Can this be done using strings?

Comment: Don't use `VARCHAR`, use `DECIMAL`; see my Addenda.